# Hreflang target different languages in different regions

Tags: seo, hreflang

I would like to know whether we can implement the hreflang tag for English audience in Germany like `hreflang="en-DE"` or it should be always like "de-DE" and "de"?

Answer (score 1):

The hreflang attributes are split into two parts, language and region. The first part is language and uses the [ISO 639-1 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes), the second part is the region in [ISO 3166-1 Alpha 2 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2).

So if you wanted to target French people in Great Britain then you would use `fr-GB` and if you wanted to target English reading and speaking people in Germany then you would want to use `en-DE`.

Google [supports both ISO 639-1 and 3166-1 Alpha 2 format](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) and therefore you can match any language with any region using the codes found in those iso's.

It should be mentioned that by using `en-DE` you are telling Google that this page is solely for English people in Germany, meaning the page may not be returned for countries outside that region, if you want all regions across the world then don't use this method, or you could simply use `hreflang="en"` if you prefer.